# Whats wrong with my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript-objects

```
            // Our person constructor
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// We can make a function which takes persons as arguments
// This one computes the difference in ages between two people
var ageDifference = function(person1, person2) {
    return person1.age - person2.age;
};

// Make a new function, olderAge, to return the age of
// the older of two people
var olderAge = function() {
      if(alice > billy){
            return alice.age;
          }
      else{
            return billy.age;
          }
    };

// Let's bring back alice and billy to test our new function
var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

console.log("The older person is " + olderAge(alice, billy));
```

So in exercise I'm doing is requierd from me to display the age of the older person . Problem is it's displaying the age of younger . Here is what it says "The older person is 25" . Here is link of the exercise that i'm doing : http://www.codecademy.com/courses/spencer-sandbox/4/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: You compare objects insteed of ages.

if (alice.age > billy.age)

Answer (score 0):

```
var olderAge = function() {
      if(alice.age > billy.age){
            return alice.age;
          }
      else{
            return billy.age;
          }
    };
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw46G/)

You might also need to check if they are the same age.